# why htpasswd from apache2-utils output redirect failed

Tags: linux, redirect, pipe, .htpasswd

while I'm trying to redirect htpasswd's out and input to a pipe file, the prompt messages always print without redirection. I tried manny method, all failed. anyone help?

*mkfifo pipe*

1. htpasswd -m aaa test &> pipe
2. htpasswd -m aaa test 2>&1 >pipe
3. htpasswd -m aaa test 2>pipe

always prompt print for-ground. Any advise is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Just close this question, for I use a purl shell script.
htpasswd can be used as silence mode:
htpasswd -b   
that all.